# Displaying Loading... animation while loading new images into website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a website which will display an image statically, I have some image thumbnails below to that Preview section and when I click on the thumbnails, the big image will be displayed on the preview section, Im using jQuery here to replace the SRC of the IMG tag while click on thumbnails, so it takes some time to display the selected image on the browser, until the new image loads it is displaying the previous one there even after few seconds of click action on thumbs(Loading time into browser depends on internet connection), so I would like to display an Image saying "Loading.." while it loads into browser.
Any help would be appreciated.
I tried with onload() for img tag, but seems it is on first time load, since im just changing the SRC value alone its not working though.
Here is my code looks like

```
function show_preview()
{
  $("#preview_loader_gif").css( "display", "block" ); //to show the loader image
     $('#big_image').attr( "src", selected_file_src); //to change the source
   $("#preview_loader_gif").css( "display", "none" ); //to hide the loader image

    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code? A demo fiddle would be great.

Comment: You could just set the loading image as the background for the elements the images load into, and when they load, they'll cover it up.

Comment: @aBhijit : Thanks, see the post, Ive posted my code there

Comment: @DaggNabbit : Thats kool, but it will works when there is no image, problem is when we click on second image the first image exists there untill second one loads, so no BG will appear here.

Comment: Using DaggNabbit's idea, you can hide the current image before loading the next(on click). So the loader will be visible.

Answer (score -1):

```
beforeSend: function () {
                    $('YOUR_SELECTOR').before('<img src="YOUR_PATH/loading.gif" class="loading">');
},
success: function(html){
         $(".loading").remove();
}
```

if you are using ajax call.

or just add show the loading image start of the show thumb method and hide it end of the method

```
<div>
<img src="image.png" id="image" />
<span class="loading">Loading...</span>
```

```
$(function(){
    //animate loading text
    $(".loading").animate({left: '+=100'},500); 

    //On image loaded, remove loading text
    $("#image").load(){
        $(".loading").remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is helpful, but not working, I tried this$("#image").load(){
        $(".loading").remove();
    }

Comment: Should be `$("#image").load(function(){ $(".loading").remove() });`. See [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).